# how to align avatar circle and text content css

Tags: html, css

I want to align text content and the avatar circle. Here are the classes that I have defined

```
.user-detail {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: right;
    
    .user-detail__username {
        margin: 18px 16px 0px 10px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        font-size: $font-size;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    .user-detail__role {
        margin: 18px 16px 0px 10px;
        display: block;
        font-size: $font-size * 0.9;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .user-detail__avatar-circle {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 8px 11px 0px 0px;
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid $lightstroke;
    }
    .user-detail__avatar {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 51px; 
        line-height: 43px; 
        left:-4px;
    }
}
```

and here is the HTML markup

```
<div class="user-detail right">
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <span class="user-detail__username">
            Adminstrator
        </span>
        <span class="user-detail__role">Adminstrator</span>
    </div>

    <div class="user-detail__avatar-circle">
        <i class="material-icons user-detail__avatar">account_circle</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

it shows like this here

[image]

I want to text and avatar circle should be bottom aligned. If I inspect element there is space on the top of text div. If I could remove this space problem will be solved. But I don't know how could I do that? Even changing the `margin` of text div not working? Any help?

Comment: Try adding `vertical-align: text-top;` to your `<div style="display:inline-block">` tag.

Comment: @DavidR setting `vertical-align: top` worked. but can you please explain what was the reason? and what is that space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual, what is a pain to achieve with traditional CSS (float, margin, inline-block, etc.) is a breeze with Flexbox.

```css
.user-detail {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: blue solid 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.user-detail>div {
  border: green solid 2px;
}

.user-detail .details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-detail right">
  <div class="details">
    <span class="user-detail__username">
            Adminstrator
        </span>
    <span class="user-detail__role">Adminstrator</span>
  </div>

  <div class="user-detail__avatar-circle">
    <i class="material-icons user-detail__avatar">account_circle</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `align-items:center;`  will it be applicable to all the elements in that div?

Comment: @Nihal Yes. If, by any reason, you want to change the alignment of only one element, you can add `align-self: auto | flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch` to that element.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Flexbox is less pain.
Try making your

```
.user-detail {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
}
```

More about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

The `vertical-align: top` setting normally align and positions your div element to top , in your case the "Administrator" text.

You need to change your html as (check the second `<div>` tag in the below code for the change),

```
<div class="user-detail right">
    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align: top">
        <span class="user-detail__username">
            Adminstrator
        </span>
        <span class="user-detail__role">Adminstrator</span>
    </div>

    <div class="user-detail__avatar-circle">
        <i class="material-icons user-detail__avatar">account_circle</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!